Integer expression with binomial coefficients
I am trying to prove that
$$
\mbox{for any natural}\ k, n,\ \mbox{where}\ k \ge n,\quad
\frac{\left(2k + 1\right)\left(k + n\right)!}
{\left(2n + 1\right)!\left(k - n\right)!}\quad \mbox{is an integer}
$$
Computer code doesn't produce counterexamples. Any ideas would be appreciated.

See art of problem solving.

As written you don't actually have any binomial coefficients. The most obvious way I can see to express in terms of binomial coefficients is as $\binom{k+n}{k-n}\cdot\frac{2k+1}{2n+1}$.
